# matlab c shared library: capturing matlab function output with mxArray*/mxArray**

Tags: c++, c, matlab, shared-libraries

I am trying to call matlab function from c code, trying to follow whatever I can get over the web. I am using matlab version R2014a running on Ubuntu 14.04. Lets say the function `testfun.m` looks like below --

```
function c = testfun(a, b)
    disp('doing testfun()');
    c = a + b ;
    disp('done testfun()');
end
```

now I invoked `mcc` to make the c-wrapper --

```
user@pc:/tmp/test$ mcc -B csharedlib:libtestfun testfun.m -v
```

then I have [`libtestfun.c`](http://pastebin.com/T46vHTm4), [`libtestfun.h`](http://pastebin.com/TSEjJtHr) and `libtestfun.so` files and I create a c file that calls the `testfun()` like this --

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libtestfun.h"

int main()
{
    libtestfunInitialize();

    mxArray *a, *b, **c;
    double *x ;

    a = mxCreateDoubleScalar(4); x = mxGetPr(a);
    printf("a = %.1f\n", x[0]);
    b = mxCreateDoubleScalar(5); x = mxGetPr(b);
    printf("b = %.1f\n", x[0]);

    *c = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
    mlfTestfun(1, c, a, b);

    x = mxGetPr(c[0]);
    printf("c = %.1f\n", x[0]);

    libtestfunTerminate();
    return 1 ;
}
```

and I am building the executable with --

```
user@pc:/tmp/test$ mbuild test.c libtestfun.c -L.libtestfun.so -v
```

the fact is that the signature for the function reads

```
LIB_libtestfun_C_API bool MW_CALL_CONV mlfTestfun(int nargout, mxArray** c, mxArray* a, mxArray* b);
```

If you notice, you can see that the output `c` is declared as `mxArray**`, therefore I am using `mxArray **c` in the `test.c` file.

But when I run the executable, I only see `0.0` as the value of `c`, but it supposed to be `9.0` --

```
user@pc:/tmp/test$ ./test 
a = 4.0
b = 5.0
c = 0.0
```

what is going on?

why is the output always declared as `mxArray**` in the function signature?
why I can't see the outputs produced by the `disp()` function in `testfun.m` ?

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `c` incorrectly. It also should be `mxArray*`. The double pointer in the signature is because it is an output. When you write `*c` you are de-referencing an uninitialized pointer.

You need the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libtestfun.h"

int main()
{
    libtestfunInitialize();

    mxArray *a;
    mxArray *b;
    mxArray *c = NULL; // output arg must be initialized to NULL
    double *x ;

    a = mxCreateDoubleScalar(4); x = mxGetPr(a);
    printf("a = %.1f\n", x[0]);
    b = mxCreateDoubleScalar(5); x = mxGetPr(b);
    printf("b = %.1f\n", x[0]);

    if (mlfTestfun(1, &c, a, b))
    {    
        x = mxGetPr(c);
        printf("c = %.1f\n", x[0]);
    }

    libtestfunTerminate();
    return 1 ;
}
```

Comment: `x = mxGetPr(c[0])` does not compile, and `x = mxGetPr(c)` gives segfault, any idea ?

Comment: Sorry. Misthink. I think that's it now.

Comment: thanks, but still gives this segfault, see http://pastebin.com/26sZCfkd, and if I say `c[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);` just before `mlfTestfun(1, c, a, b);` then it runs but still `c` is `0.0`

Comment: thanks for your time, but `if(mlfTestfun(..))` is always false, :-(

Comment: Ok, looks like the function call failed!

Comment: I wonder what happens if you remove the two disp calls and recompile the matlab?

Comment: no change, removed the `disp()`s but still the same.

Comment: What happens when you execute the mcc samples?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85030/discussion-between-ramgorur-and-david-heffernan).